# Combinatorics - How many ways to partition an integer n into k bins with values 0 - 5 and restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

I have been struggling with this brain teaser for some time now. I looked at some combinatorics and partition equations but I can't find the one that captures the solution entirely.

**Frame**

I have a set with 6 elements (bins) { a , b , c , d , e , f }.

Each element in the set can take an integer value in the range (0,5).

The value N is given by N = a + b + c + d + e + f: The total range for N is (0,30).

**Question**

For each value of N in the range (0,30) how many unique combinations of elements can I have in the set without repetition.

e.g. if N = 30 there is only 1 possible unique combination {5,5,5,5,5,5}

also for     N =  0 there is only 1 possible unique combination {0,0,0,0,0,0}

```
 for     N =  1 there are 6 possible unique combinations {1,0,0,0,0,0}
                                                         {0,1,0,0,0,0}
                                                         {0,0,1,0,0,0}
                                                         {0,0,0,1,0,0}
                                                         {0,0,0,0,1,0}
                                                         {0,0,0,0,0,1}
```

Therefore N can be described as a discrete normally distributed integer random variable in the range (0,30).

Please help.

Comment: If you are familiar with [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function), you want the coefficient of $N$ in the expansion of $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^6$.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking how many ways there are to roll $n$ with $k$ dice, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970523/how-many-ways-can-the-average-of-n-dice-be-a/970813#970813

Answer (score 1):

You could as suggested by [N. F. Taussig](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043222/combinatorics-how-many-ways-to-partition-an-integer-n-into-k-bins-with-values/3043749?noredirect=1#comment6273509_3043222) use the generating function $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)^6$ and the answer will be the coefficient of $x^N$ of the expanded function.

Otherwise This question can be solved using the technique described [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/)

Let there be $N$ stars. Since you want to separate them into $6$ bins, you will need to use $5$ bars. The $5$ bars will "split" the balls into 6 bins. The permutation will always be of the form $$\{(bin~a)|(bin~b)|(bin~c)|(bin~d)|(bin~e)|(bin~f)\}$$ Any permutation of the $N$ stars and $5$ bars will result in a unique solution. The number of ways that it can be arranged where $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ non-negative is $N+5\choose 5$.

However, this will include cases where the bins can be more than 5. We will need to exclude the cases where $a, b, c, d, e$ or $f$ is greater than 5. This can be achieved by the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion. We would first subtract the case where only one of $a, b, c, d, e$ or $f$ is greater than 5. This is equivalent to doing the above but with $N-6$ instead of $N$. There are ${6\choose 1}$ ways for a bin to be more than 5. Hence you would subtract ${6\choose 1}{N-6\choose 5}$ from the total number of ways. However in this you will also notice that the case where 2 of the bins is greater than 5 was included twice. You would repeat the steps until the number of ways to have more than 5 balls in $j$ bins become zero.

The general formula would hence be $$\sum_{j=0}^{floor(\frac{N}{6})} (-1)^j\binom{6}{j}\binom{N+5-6j}{5}$$.

Comment: Be careful.  Your solution includes those cases in which there are more than five stars in a bin.

Comment: Oops sorry I will correct it.

Comment: Still .. another correction to do : the limit of summation is $\left\lfloor N/6 \right\rfloor $ and not $\left\lfloor (N+5)/6 \right\rfloor $: See my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. forgot that $N+5-6j >= 5$ not $0$

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in general reads as
$$N_{\,b} (s,r,m) = \text{No}\text{. of solutions to}\;\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 \leqslant \text{integer  }x_{\,j}  \leqslant r \hfill \\
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  +  \cdots  + x_{\,m}  = s \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$$
where $N_b$ is expressed through the sum
$$
N_b (s,r,m)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers  }s,m,r} \right.\quad  =
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\,\,k\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\frac{s}{r+1}\, \leqslant \,m} \right)} 
{\left( { - 1} \right)^k \binom{m}{k}
 \binom
 { s + m - 1 - k\left( {r + 1} \right) } 
 { s - k\left( {r + 1} \right)}\ }
$$
and whose o.g.f. in $s$ is as already suggested by N.F. Taussig
$$
F_b (x,r,m) = \sum\limits_{0\,\, \leqslant \,\,s\,\,\left( { \leqslant \,\,r\,m} \right)} {N_b (s,r,m)\;x^{\,s} }
  = \left( {1 + x +  \cdots  + x^{\,r} } \right)^m  = \left( {\frac{{1 - x^{\,r + 1} }}{{1 - x}}} \right)^m 
$$

The above is thoroughly explained in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420) and in [this paper](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm).

In your case,  you just have to put $m=6,\;r=5,\; s=N$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves it perfectly. I can use this for analysis immediately although it will take further time to understand it.

Comment: @EmmanuelUwechue: glad it helps. A further explanation of how it is built is the "inclusion-exclusion" principle described by S.F. Cheong, which is better grasped if you read the "geometric" interpretation given in the other cited post.